# MySQL Inner Join Between Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to JOIN two tables in `MySQL`. Here is my table:

**Games Table**:

```
GameID      Date/Time          PlayerOneID   PlayerTwoID
 13    12/10/2013 10:53:29 PM     1              2    
 14    12/10/2013 10:57:29 PM     1              2
 15    12/10/2013 10:58:29 PM     2              1
```

I have another table contain the ID of a player and that players name.

**Players Table**:

```
1   Dan
2   Jon
```

I'd like the resulting table to look like the following:

```
GameID      Date/Time          PlayerOneID   PlayerTwoID
 13    12/10/2013 10:53:29 PM     Dan        Jon      
 14    12/10/2013 10:57:29 PM     Dan        Jon
 15    12/10/2013 10:58:29 PM     Jon        Dan
```

Here's what I am currently doing:

```
SELECT Games.GameID, Games.`Date/Time`, Players.Name, PlayerTwoID
FROM Games

INNER JOIN Players
ON PlayerOneID = Players.ID
```

This gets PlayerOnes name, but I can't find away to get PlayerTwos name as well. I have tried using two INNER JOINS, but this hasn't worked. I've read a lot of posts here on the stack, but I haven't come across any solution that works. I am new to MySQL, so a follow up explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track, you do need to join to the Players table twice, like so:

```
SELECT Games.GameID, Games.`Date/Time`, p1.Name, p2.Name
FROM Games
INNER JOIN Players p1
ON PlayerOneID = p1.ID
INNER JOIN Players p2
ON PlayerTwoID = p2.ID
```

What you probably missed was using an alias (p1,p2) to differentiate between the two copies of the Players table you are joining to.

Comment: Thanks! Thats really weird though.. I already tried that and it didn't work. Could it have been because I used Players.Name, Players.Name instead of p1.Name, p2.Name?

Comment: @Jonathan - Ha, yup, was just updating my answer to suggest that.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select GameID, p1.name playerOneName,p2.name playerTwoName from
games inner join players p1 on games.playerOneID=p1.id
inner join players p2 on games.playerTwoID=p2.id
order by GameID asc;
```

[image: the terminal execution result is shown]