# how can id assign foreign key mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have created at 2 tables. These tables are Department, employee.

Now i want to assign foreign key in department table and **join** with employee table.

have any idea??

```
SELECT id,department FROM department; 
SELECT * FROM `employee'
```

Comment: use Inner join as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527582/mysql-inner-join-between-two-tables

Comment: Normally its employee -> department logic ri8. Each employee has a foreign key dep_id.

Comment: Put department id in employee table, if structure is simple otherwise create an identity table if department may change.

Answer (score 3):

```
create employee table field are- id(primary key),name,dept_id
department table fields are-dept_id(primary key),name
```

after select the dept_id.give index.
[image]

than select the department table and dept_id.than click save button.
[image]

Comment: What is this ? Better ask question in comment section .

Comment: I want foreign key department table and how to join employee table

Comment: add dept_id field in employee table.

Comment: I cannot understand the answer.
Because i am new in php.
If you don r mine any body explain different method

Comment: @sarathi can you explain what you exactly need to find out here?

Comment: @sarathi ok than tell me employee and department field

Comment: department table id, department
employee table id, name, department

Comment: @sarathi ok change department  field id to dept_id.employee table department to dept_id.so your department fields are dept_id,department.employee table fields are id,name,dept_id.

Comment: than open your employee table structure ..give index to dept_id

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:-

```
$query="select emp.name, dep.department from employee emp 
INNER JOIN 
department dep ON 
emp.department=dep.department 
order by emp.name asc";
```

Comment: this code where i put in php 
like dbconnect.php or other

Comment: you can run this query updated with your fields in the phpmyadmin sql query window.